# Is URL without HTTP a hyperlink for SEO?

Tags: seo, links, spam

In my spam check I don't accept comments which contain a `http://` or `https://`.

But many spam I'm getting are specifying this in HTML:

```
<a href="www.example.com" .....
```

Can this link be considered as valid by Google for SEO rankings? Since some links like this are able to sneak into my sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that link were in a web page it would be a relative link.  If it were on `http://somesite.com` it would refer to `http://somesite.com/www.example.com` -- broken link.

In many email clients, links like this may work because the links are opened in a browser and the browser has no context to make the link relative.  Its unclear whether links like that would work with web mail clients (maybe some of them add the `http://` before displaying it).

As far as SEO goes, formatting links like that on a website would cause broken links which would hurt SEO rather than help it.

Comment: It is more important how Google sees it since link mistakingly passed through my moderation could be a spammed site in view of Google and my site will be penalized for linking to it. Thanks for your answer.